# How to upload to Google Drive Storage from an iOS app via Service Account Authentication?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I did not find any solution for iphone application. Please help me for IOS app.

I have done with android application by the following code :

```
java.io.File file = getTempPkc12File();

    ArrayList<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
    scopes.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE_SCRIPTS);

    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();

    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file).build();

    service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
            .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect everything you need to know is covered in these documentation sections:

[Quickstart: Uploading a file/image to Drive on iOS](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart)

[Handling Auth Requests in iOS Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/auth)

[Uploading Files using Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads)

[Working with File content using Drive API in iOS Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files)